# How to mint NFT using ethers.js?

Tags: erc-721, ethers.js, dapp-development, mint, sendtransaction

I'm a beginner in blockchain dev...

I'm using the famous Hashlips ERC721 smart contract (available here: https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_contract/blob/main/contract/SimpleNft_flat.sol ).

The SC is working great via Remix.

Now I want to be able to interact with that SC from a Sveltekit app I made, using the ethers.js library. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to send the transaction :-(.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  import token from "../images/token.gif";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import abi from "../data/abi.json";
  import { ethers } from "ethers";
  import { signerAddressStore } from "../stores/signerAddressStore";
  import { signerStore } from "../stores/signerStore";
  import { contractStore } from "../stores/contractStore";

  let isConnected = false;
  let contractData = {
    cost: "",
    maxSupply: "",
    totalSupply: "",
  };

  onMount(async function () {
    await connectMetamask();
    await getContract();
    console.log(signer);
  });

  let provider, signer;

  const connectMetamask = async () => {
    try {
      provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
      signer = provider.getSigner();
      const address = await signer.getAddress();
      signerAddressStore.set(address);
      signerStore.set(signer);
      isConnected = true;
    } catch (error) {
      isConnected = false;
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getContract = async () => {
    const contractAddress = import.meta.env.VITE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
    const contractAbi = abi;
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);
    contractStore.set(contract);

    contractData.cost =
      parseInt(await $contractStore.cost()) / 1000000000000000000;
    contractData.maxSupply = parseInt(await $contractStore.maxSupply());
    contractData.totalSupply = parseInt(await $contractStore.totalSupply());

    console.log(contractData);
  };

  const mint = async () => {

    const tx = {
      from: $signerAddressStore,
      to: import.meta.env.VITE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.02"),
      nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount($signerAddressStore, "latest"),
      gasLimit: "3000000",
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.hexlify(parseInt(await provider.getGasPrice())),
    };

    try {
      await $contractStore.mint(1);
      await $signerStore.sendTransaction(tx);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

</script>
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ]
```

I don't understand how to proceed...

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the contract address is right.
Next, try removing `gasPrice`, `gasLimit` and `nonce` from your transaction and let Metamask calculate those for you.

Just try to execute the transaction with

```
// create provider from Metamask
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
// get the account that will pay for the trasaction
const signer = provider.getSigner()

let contract = new ethers.Contract(
      contractAddress,
      abi,
      signer
    )


const tx = await contract.mint(1);

console.log('transaction :>> ', tx)
// wait for the transaction to actually settle in the blockchain
await tx.wait()
```

Comment: I got this: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] . And not sure it's the right way since I don't give the value ... ?

Comment: Check if your wallet has any pending transactions, you might be sending transactions with the same nonce. Here is an article with more details about that: https://chainstack.com/a-developers-guide-to-the-transactions-in-mempool-metamask-edition/